# Haskell passing class with Num to Int

Tags: haskell

I am writing code in Haskell that acts like take, except it takes elements from the end of a list.

```
snatch :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> [b] -> [b]
snatch n _
     | n <= 0 = []
snatch _ [] = []
snatch n x = reverse (take n (reverse x))
```

The problem is with this line,

```
snatch n x = reverse (take n (reverse x))
```

It basically states that for take n, n has to be an Int.  However, a is a Num type.  If I change the definition of the function to this,

```
snatch :: Int -> [b] -> [b]
```

Then it works fine.  I've tried reading the docs and searching the internet.  But I can't find out why.  Int is apparently a class of Num.  So shouldn't this work? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Beware of terminology: `Num` is a class, but `Int` is a type, and not a class. We say that `Int` is an instance of `Num`.

Comment: `Num` seems the wrong constraint here, `Integral` looks better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`take`, as the name suggests, takes `n` elements. Going by your logic, if `Num` was the only criteria, then your function should be able to take, say, 5.4343 elements from the list. Only, that doesn't make sense.

Therefore, in this case, even if `Int` is an instance of `Num`, the properties required are those specific to `Int`.